# How are simultaneous updates to a single document handled in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have two clients updating the same document at about the same time:

```
{ 
     a: "1",
     b: "2",
}
```

Client A changes a to "8" and client B changes b to "9".  Does rethinkdb guarantee the following will be the final result?

```
{ 
     a: "8",
     b: "9",
}
```

If it does not (i.e. the result may sometimes be 1 & 9 or 2 & 8) then is it the case that to avoid data getting 'trounced' in this way that every writer has to have it's own dedicated tables and/or rows?

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really final result will be:

```
{ 
     a: "8",
     b: "9",
}
```

But, if, for example, 3d client tries to read this record between 2 updates, he possible will get:

```
{ 
     a: "8",
     b: "2",
}
```

Comment: trounce it is.  too bad rethinkdb went away.

Comment: @bunt what? O_o

Comment: not sure what O_o is, referring to [blog](https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdb-shutdown/).  Maybe went away is too strong, how about 'paused'.  Whichever, was too bad.

Comment: https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/rethinkdb-joins-linux-foundation/ They are joins The Linux Foundation